# Множественный запрос к Firestore на swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-database, firestore

Начал изучать Firestore от Google. У меня есть коллекция Users и документы в виде UID. Как мне составить запрос так, что бы я мог получить профили этих юзеров, например у меня может быть от 1 до 100 UID и мне нужно получить все эти профили по их UID. Спасибо!
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0):

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516763/firestore-swift-4-how-to-get-total-count-of-all-the-documents-inside-a-collect)

Попробуйте так:

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments() 
{ 
    (querySnapshot, err) in

    if let err = err 
    {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
    } 
    else 
    {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
        }

        print("Count = \(count)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("Users").document(uid) //получить один документ по uid
db.collection("Users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)// или так через query
db.collection("Users").getDocuments() // получить все документы(так делать не нужно, нужно лимитировать выдачу)
db.collection("Users").getDocuments().limit(to: 3)//Вот так, а затем грузить еще если надо.
```